# In Codeception, How to print a variable?

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I'm a new developer. I want to know, how can I print a variable in `yii2` codeception testing.

Can I have some examples?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to debug your tests, `var_dump($variable); die;` is a good option.

Comment: If you want to add some extra logging, use `codecept_debug('message')` and run codeception with `-vv` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the --debug key when testing for debuging.

```
./yii tests --debug
```

Also for unit-tests you can use (examples):

- for ActorHelper:

  ```
  $this->comment($email);
  ```
- for Tester:

  ```
  $I->comment($email);
  ```